# How do I inventory the type and speed of a remote computer?

Tags: hardware, memory, audit

I'm on a Windows 2003/2008 corporate network with 100 users.  I've been tasked with increasing the RAM on all end-user workstations.

The problem is we have a mixture of different computers in our environment.  Some are Dell, some HP, and some workstations we built from scratch.  Needless to say, these machines all do not share the same memory type or speed.

I know I can go to each one of these 100 computers one-by-one to find the memory information.  But I'd rather find a less time-costly and more elegant solution.

Is there a way for me to remotely inventory/audit these machines to find the specific memory type (SDRAM, DDR, DDR2, etc.), speed, and slot configuration?

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Use [OCS Inventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php?page=features):

> Information about Hardware and
>   Operating System are collected.
>
> Memory slot arrays : Caption and
>   description, Capacity in MB, Purpose
>   (system memory, flash memory...), Type
>   of memory (SDRAM, DDR...), Speed in
>   MHz, Slot number.

Comment: We use this (in addition to GLPI, because the OCS webpage looks like it was drawn in crayon), and it works amazingly well

Answer (score 4):

[Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com) will do that for you, and much more...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to access the WMI interface of Windows. You can do it via PowerShell, [KiXtart](http://www.kixtart.org/) or other languages or script.

If a hardware driver wants to share some informations with the system, you find them in WMI interface.

Comment: +1.  I'm a big fan of VBScript and am coming to appreciate Powershell.  The Microsoft Technet Script Center http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us and Scriptomatic2 from Microsoft can get you far.

Answer (score 1):

[Scriptomatic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939957.aspx) is painfully easy to use.  It can get you any information available via WMI, without coding or debugging said code.  Happy little GUI interface; very shallow learning curve.

I've used it to pull that info from a text file of computer names in very little time.  It can probably get information from a domain or OU pretty easily, but I haven't personally gone that far.

Comment: I wouldn't call the GUI good, but it does a fantastic job of exposing available WMI classes and properties to you!  If you're going to learn VBScript, JScript, WSH, and/or Powershell, you definitely need to have Scriptomatic2.  From there, you read the Scripting Guy articles on running scripts against multiple computers

Comment: @gWaldo you're right, the interface definitely has school project quality.  I love anything you can learn at home, experimenting & driving the family crazy.  ;)

Comment: That just gave me a mental image of the parents coming home to find their kid has disassembled the TV...  And it made me smile.  Scriptomatic is ugly, but once you come to appreciate it, it's like a beloved but ugly dog.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com) (freeware) for this, it has a build-in report to show how many slots are occupied and how many are still available.

Answer (score 0):

After a short search I found these softwares, but I didn't try them.

- [Cool Info FX](http://www.tometasoftware.com/products_cifx.asp)
- [Total Network Inventory](http://www.softinventive.com/products/total-network-inventory/)

Answer (score 0):

[Network Inventory Advisor](http://www.clearapps.com) does an awesome job for network, software, hardware inventory. Scans Windows, MAC OS, Linux, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used several of them: Spiceworks, Lansweeper and TNI (Total Network Inventory) and im sticking to the last one for now. Spiceworks works too slow and Lansweeper is pricier than TNI. (paid version, of course). They all also provide [software license management](http://www.softinventive.com/software-license-management/) and [pc audit](http://www.softinventive.com/pc-audit/) with all parts and componnets installed in a computer. Lansweeper and TNI dont need satellites to work